# one chapter affects layout of the next one

Tags: vertical-alignment, footnotes, chapters

I maintain a very long document, which I usually process chapter by chapter, then compile the whole when the chapter I changed satisfies my needs.

however, I saw an inconsistency in one of my chapters - when compiled alone it's ok, but when compiled with the others it's changed and needs new pagination.

I reduced the problem to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extbook}
\edef\dimmbottom{1.4cm}
\edef\dimmouter{2.2cm}
\edef\dimminner{2.8cm}
\edef\dimmtoptop{0.5cm}
\edef\dimmtophead{0.8cm}
\edef\dimmtopset{\dimexpr\dimmtoptop+\dimmtophead}
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm,paperheight=14.8cm,inner=\dimmouter,outer=\dimminner,headsep=0cm,headheight=\dimmtophead,top=\dimmtopset,bottom=\dimmbottom,footskip=12pt,marginparwidth=0.5cm,marginparsep=1.1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\chapter{first}
\hfill %comment out this line, and see the difference!
\chapter{second}
\newpage
a\\ a\\ a\\ a\\ a\\ a\\ a\\ a\\ a\\ a\\ a\\ a\\ a\\ a\\ a\\ a\\ a\\
\vspace{-15pt}

a\footnotetext{a\\}\\
\end{document}
```

when the 1st chapter contains the "hfill" line, the last line of the 2nd(!) chapter appears on the next page (along with its footnote).
when you comment out the "hfill" in the 1st chapter, all lines of the 2nd appear on a single page (although a blank page is added, due to the "\" at the end of the footnote).

I know using "\" is usually not a good idea, however my real text is kind of poetry and I need to break short lines.
also using the ugly "vspace" trick may seem like a bad idea too, but I have my reasons (mostly huge legacy code, automatically generated, that I try to avoid changing as much as I can).

my question is mainly about the inconsistency - where such a small change in chapter 1 severely affects a line in chapter 2 (in reality there are tens of pages between the line that causes the problem and where it appears, they have very complex contents and layout, and all of this doesn't seem to change at all)!

this implies I can't rely on compiling a single chapter, but must compile the whole doc (876 pages) for any simple change I test.

I use xelatex (the original doc contains bidi unicode text).

EDIT: I changed the title of the question - the issue here is not the "hfill", but the "chapter". I assumed that opening a chapter, that is clearing a double page, would "reset" the layout engine, but this example shows I was wrong.
so what should I add to my chapter openings in order to guarantee that reset?

Comment: Some issue with the `textbook` package. Problem does not occur if you use the `book` package for instance.

Comment: I see no real problem: if you don't have a paragraph after the first `\chapter`, the settings LaTeX does for avoiding page breaks are still in force when the second `\chapter` is scanned. Doing `\newpage` after `\chapter` is something I'd not recommend.

Comment: @peter, it happens in book too. use \documentclass[11pt]{book} and add \Large after \begin{document} .
this gives you the same layout approximately, and the problem reproduces very much the same.

Comment: @egreg, the \newpage is not real - I added it only to space vertically for the example. it's not in my real doc.
also, I tried adding a blank line after the \hfill line. the problem persists.